# I have nested some routes with lazyloading but only show component from default nested route in / route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I have a HomeComponent that i want to show at / route

HomeComponent.hmtl

```
<header>
 <div>
  <h1>CommunityPost</h1>
 </div>
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onLogout()">Log Out</button>
</header>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<main>
 <nav mat-tab-nav-bar  [tabPanel]="tabPanel">
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/users" (click)="activeLink = '/users'" 
   [active]="activeLink == '/users'" > COMMUNITY</a>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/posts" (click)="activeLink = '/posts'" 
   [active]="activeLink == '/posts'" > POSTS </a>
 </nav>
 <mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </mat-tab-nav-panel>
</main>
```

In router-outlet i want to show the children routes

app-route

```
const routes: Routes = [
`enter code here`{path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [guardGuard], children:[
 {path: 'posts', loadChildren: () => import('./posts/posts.module').then(m => 
        m.PostsModule)},
 {path: 'users', loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => 
        m.UserModule)},
 {path: '', redirectTo: 'users', pathMatch: 'full'},
  ]},
{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
{path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent},
 ];
```

users-route

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {path: '', component: UsersListComponent}, 
   {path: 'users/:id', component: UserDetailComponent},
  ];
```

This show in / route the UserListComponent instead of HomeComponent and the UserList nested in it

Edit HomeComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.css'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  activeLink: string 





constructor(private router: Router){
    this.router.events.subscribe((data: NavigationEnd)=> {
      if(data.url !== undefined){
        this.activeLink=data.url
      }
    })
  }

  onLogout(){
    if(window.confirm('You are logging out. Are you sure?')){
      localStorage.removeItem('auth')
      window.location.reload()  
    }
  }
  
  

}
```

If i go to localhost/ it will show only UserListComponent , but when I go to localhost/users it will show HomeComponent and the nested UsersListComponent as it shlould be

stackblitz to all project: [https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/DoublEffe/communitypost](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/DoublEffe/communitypost)

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

I finally found the problem to your issue, you are importing `UserModule`
and `PostsModule` in the `AppModule` once I removed this everything worked fine!

## Key takeaway!

**Lazy loaded modules need not be imported on the main module, this will only cause routing issues!**

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/DoublEffe/communitypost)

---

Actually the code shared, did not have any major issues, I think the problem might be on the root component level, please check the below stackblitz for reference, if still facing issues, please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated and details on what needs fixing!

home component!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `<header>
  <div>
   <h1>CommunityPost</h1>
  </div>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onLogout()">Log Out</button>
 </header>
 <mat-divider></mat-divider>
 <main>
  <nav mat-tab-nav-bar  [tabPanel]="tabPanel">
   <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/users" (click)="activeLink = '/users'" 
    [active]="activeLink == '/users'" > COMMUNITY</a>
   <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/posts" (click)="activeLink = '/posts'" 
    [active]="activeLink == '/posts'" > POSTS </a>
  </nav>
  <mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-tab-nav-panel>
 </main>`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule, CommonModule, MatTabsModule, MatDividerModule],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  activeLink = '';
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onLogout() {}
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-plclu3?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fuser%2Fusers-list%2Fusers-list.component.ts,src%2Fuser%2Fuser-detail%2Fuser-detail.component.ts,src%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts,src%2Fposts%2Fposts-list%2Fposts-list.component.ts,src%2Fposts%2Fposts.module.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: For me is a route problem becuase when i go to localhost/users it show both HomeComponent and the UsersListComponent as should be but at localhost/ rote is missing HomeComponent

Comment: @FabioFagiani Actually the empty route `''` is matched with home, which is correct, we should show the navbar of home wherever screen we go

Comment: I added my HomeComponent, I am feeling this issue is a stupid thing that I am missing

Comment: @FabioFagiani try removing the `guardGuard` and try checking, your code will never go to `localhost/` because when there no child route, it will automatically redirect to `users` on `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'users', pathMatch: 'full' },` try replicating the issue in the stackblitz and share back if its not resolved, also check the baseHref in index.html maybe that is the problem!

Comment: I added the whole project but when I opened it it gave 404 error can you see it?

Comment: @FabioFagiani I finally found the problem to your issue, you are importing `UserModule`
 and `PostsModule` in the `AppModule` once I removed this everything worked fine [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/DoublEffe/communitypost)